# Check for file existence

Tags: file, batch-file, command, prompt

I'm looking to write a script that will load up a file that has a bunch of directory/filenames in CSV format, and then output what files are not found.

This is what I have so far:

`for /f "delims=, tokens=1,2,3" %i in (C:\foo.csv) do dir "Y:\%i\%j\%k" >> C:\temp\log.txt`

Which outputs everything.

What I really want is for it to log nothing if it is found, and then just a single line error of something similar to:

`File AC\0d\234csf-234wfv-423vx-23fsdfs.jpg was not found`

But right now it logs everything.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to use the command interactively so here's a solution to be used directly in the console:

```
for /f "delims=, tokens=1,2,3" %i in (C:\foo.csv) do dir "Y:\%i\%j\%k" >nul 2>nul || echo File "Y:\%i\%j\%k" was not found>> C:\temp\log.txt
```

A more readable multi-line version (to be used in a batch script, obviously, hence `%%` instead of `%`):

```
for /f "delims=, tokens=1,2,3" %%i in (C:\foo.csv) do (
dir "Y:\%%i\%%j\%%k" >nul 2>nul || echo File "Y:\%%i\%%j\%%k" was not found>> C:\temp\log.txt
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `if not exist`. You should also put the `delims` at the end, to be able to specify space as a separator, besides the comma.

Here's what you need:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=, tokens=1,2,3" %%i in (foo.csv) do (
    if not exist Y:\%%i\%%j\%%k (
        echo Y:\%%i\%%j\%%k doesn't exist >> log.txt
    )
)
```

Comment: I've tried running this and it seems that it is just outputting everything after the `do` to stdout for each line in the file and saying that the files don't exist (When they in fact do).  Is there another part that I'm missing?

Comment: strange, it works for me. An stupid idea, do you have `echo off` ?

Answer (score -1):

try `c:\ if /?` and study the help shown , look for exists.